# Auto Fill scrollview with UIButtons from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

I need to fill a view becoming the contents of a NSArray object in a UIButtons and if the number of buttons does not fit the view to scroll. For example, if the array.count is 25 and only fit 20 buttons, 4 columns of 5 rows, the 5 remaining buttons are to be displayed by scrolling.

I'm currently testing it so:

```
    UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 728, 984)];
    sv.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    sv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(PAGE_WIDTH, sv.frame.size.height);
sv.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:sv]; // assuming a view controller

    NSMutableArray *freeHoursList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"10"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"11"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"17"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"18"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"19"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"10"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"11"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"17"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"18"],
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"19"],nil];
for (int i = 0; i < freeHoursList.count; i++)
{
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(i * (BUTTON_WIDTH + BUTTON_PADDING), 10, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
btn.tag = i + MAGIC_BUTTON_TAG_OFFSET; // to relate to the array index
    NSString *numero = [freeHoursList objectAtIndex:i];
[btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",numero]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[sv addSubview:btn];

}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with adding variable that keeps track of an actual Y position and an actual column. So you would check if the next button fits the width of the scroll and if its not - set column to 0 and add X to the button Y position. It would looks like this:

```
int BUTTON_Y = 10;
int column = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < freeHoursList.count; i++, column++)
{       
    if(column*(BUTTON_WIDTH + BUTTON_PADDING) + BUTTON_WIDTH > sv.contentSize.width) {
        BUTTON_Y += BUTTON_HEIGHT;
        column = 0;
    }

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];   
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(column * (BUTTON_WIDTH + BUTTON_PADDING), BUTTON_Y, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    btn.tag = column + MAGIC_BUTTON_TAG_OFFSET; // to relate to the array index
        NSString *numero = [freeHoursList objectAtIndex:i];
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",numero]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [sv addSubview:btn];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwswer but now I have 6 columns of buttons but in the right of the last column fill anoter 2 buttons.

Comment: So what exactly do you want? What you have now?

Comment: Sorry, I think it's because of the width and height values ​​that are defined ...

Comment: Yes, it is skipping to the next row based on BUTTON_WITH and BUTTON_PADDING :)